# In laravel, how to declare global variables avaible to all blade files?

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to use data in multiple views throughout my project, but I don't have an example of what I want to share. I have read about the View::composer method, but I am not sure if this is the right approach. Can anyone provide an example of how to use this method or suggest an alternative method for sharing data across all views in Laravel?

I have find this syntax :

```
 public function boot()
    {
        // Using class based composers...
        View::composer('profile', ProfileComposer::class);
 
        // Using closure based composers...
        View::composer('dashboard', function ($view) {
            //
        });
    }
```

Thank you !

Comment: I searched for "*laravel variable all views*" and the [first result was the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views): "***Sharing Data With All Views***: *Occasionally, you may need to share data with all views that are rendered by your application. You may do so using the View facade's share method.*"

Comment: Yes me too, but i just want to know how people do, and in the docs it's just one way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider** file in boot method you can add the varibale and then use it any blade **View**:

```
public function boot()
{
    $media_url="https://www.google.com/";
    $subject = Subject::get();

    view()->share('media_url', $media_url);
    view()->share('subject', $subject);
}
```

Now you can use **$media_url, $subject** on any of your blade directly.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has a section about this: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

```
public function boot()
{
    View::share('global_value', 'yep this is a global value');
}
```

Comment: Thank you! In the example, we can share data from the appServiceProvider. Is it possible to do the same with a controller, for example, by a return of a method that is defined globally?

Comment: For that you can use helper functions : https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers

Comment: You can call the `View` facade from any where. It's not really the Laravel way to do it, but I guess you could call it from a controller method. I wouldn't recommend it.